# Count by location by day in SQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a table of transactions that I would like to write a query for that counts the number of transactions for each location by day.  I've written the following query which only counts the total transactions for the time period that's specified in the Where clause:

```
    Select Date_Format(T.Date,'%m-%d-%y') as Date, S.StoreLocation, 
    Count(S.StoreLocation) as Transactions
    From Transactions T
    Inner Join Stores S on T.StoreCode=S.StoreCode
    Where T.Date Between '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
    Group By S.StoreLocation
```

To clarify, each row in the table is one transaction, so I just need to count the number of rows by location and by day.  I'm hoping to do this because I need to count these transactions by day by location going back multiple years which will be tens of millions of transactions.

I'd like for the output data to look something like this:

**Date**      | **StoreLocation** | **Transactions**
08-01-2017 | Location 1    | 500
08-02-2017 | Location 1    | 450
08-03-2017 | Location 1    | 600

...And so on and so forth for each of the over 100 locations and for the specified time period.

Also note that our Dates are listed in the table in the format "2017-08-01 00:00:00", which is why i was changing their format in the query to just show by day.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Add Date_Format(T.Date,'%m-%d-%y') to your group by

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I'm in the process of writing a sql fiddle example but on my phone that takes ages so I'm giving the user something to try out in the meantime

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I was talking to the OP

Comment: Ha! I totally misread that @Strawberry!

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there, all you are missing is the date inside your `GROUP BY`
When you are writing a SQL script such as this, your question actually provides the answer

> **count**s the number of **transactions** for each **location** by **day**

1. *Counts the number of transactions* is your aggregate function `COUNT(S.StoreLocation)`
2. *for each location* is the first `GROUP BY` clause
3. *by day* is the second `GROUP BY` clause.

.

```
SELECT   Date_Format(T.Date,'%m-%d-%y') AS Date
        ,S.StoreLocation
        ,COUNT(S.StoreLocation) AS Transactions
FROM     Transactions T
         INNER JOIN Stores S
             ON T.StoreCode = S.StoreCode
WHERE    T.Date BETWEEN '2017-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY S.StoreLocation
        ,Date_Format(T.Date,'%m-%d-%y')
```

A working example can be found here: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf571e/1)